# search with special characters in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am not able to do a search in a Elasticsearch with character ending/starting with special character. like "123456!"

```
{
 "query": {
    "query_string": {
        "default_field": "password",
        "query": "123456!"
    }
 }
}
```

My mappings are

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "passwords": { 
      "properties": {
        "date":    { "type": "date"}, 
        "password":    { "type": "string","index": "not_analyzed"}, 

      }
    }
  }
}
```

It is giving me error, what can I do in my search query (or in the mapping), so that special characters will be treated as part of search string ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since your `password` field is `not_analyzed` (good!), try to do an exact match by surrounding `123456!` with double quotes:

```
{
 "query": {
    "query_string": {
        "default_field": "password",
        "query": "\"123456!\""
    }
 }
}
```

Another way of doing this is to set the `keyword` analyzer in your `query_string` query (but make sure to escape the `!` because it's a [reserved character](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters) (for the `NOT` operator)

```
{
 "query": {
    "query_string": {
        "default_field": "password",
        "query": "123456\!",
        "analyzer": "keyword"
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Vals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37703189/410624) answer, one could also escape the `query` using the `escape` parameter:

```
{
 "query": {
    "query_string": {
        "default_field": "password",
        "query": "123456!",
        "analyzer": "keyword",
        "escape": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use any of the characters which function as operators in your query itself (and not as operators), then you should escape them with a leading backslash.

When using JSON for the request body, two preceding backslashes (\) are required; the backslash is a reserved escaping character in JSON strings.

```
{
  "query" : {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "kimchy\\!"
    }
  }
}
```