# Kibana Filter for multiple keyword

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I need assistance with multiple filtering of data .For example for the sample JSON below what query will work best If I have to just search for all the fields as "Apple" and fruit "Y"

1)

```
{
  "_index": "abc",
  "_type": "123",
  {
  "field" : "Apple"
  "fruit" : "Y"
  },
  {
  "field" : "Tomato"
  "fruit"   : "N"
  },
 {
  "field" : "Mango"
  "fruit"   : "Y"
}
```

2)

```
{
  "_index": "abc",
  "_type": "123",
  {
  "field" : "Apple"
  "fruit" : "N"
  },
  {
  "field" : "Tomato"
  "fruit"   : "Y"
  },
 {
  "field" : "Mango"
  "fruit"   : "Y"
 }
```

Comment: In Kibana,{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "field": "Apple"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "fruit": "Y"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: But there was no result.Can you assist further?

Comment: possibly because `term` will give you exact match, you may want to try out `match` and feel free to read a bit of `filter` use case, in your case it should be `must` in place of `filter`

Comment: updated answer please see

Comment: Hi Aashish,Thanks a lot for your help .I could manage to filter out matching field= Apple with fruit = Y but it is not filtering fruit ='?'.It seem that special charecters are not considered while filtering .Any idea how I can get through to this?   {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match": {
          "field": "Apple"
        }},
        {"match": {
          "fruit": "Y"
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: Maybe @val answer helps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703017/search-with-special-characters-in-elasticsearch) , also there's a link in the answer you would like to look into!

Comment: Hi Aashish,I tried everything ,including val's answer.but the problem is that I do not want search data to pick fruit = '?'.Rite now with the query above ,it is picking all fruits= 'y' along with '?'.

Comment: {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "field": "Apple"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "fruit": "Y"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "fruit": "\"?!\"",
            "analyser": "Keyword"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: as mentiond in answer [term](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_most_important_queries.html#_term_query) shall be handy to get exact match results, The sample query is also show in answer. Probably that shall help!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you would like to look into [ES search docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/query-dsl-intro.html#_combining_multiple_clauses) and into [ES Filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#query-filter-context)
Hope this helps you get idea of doing search:

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must":     { "match": { "tweet": "elasticsearch" }},
        "must_not": { "match": { "name":  "mary" }},
        "should":   { "match": { "tweet": "full text" }},
        "filter":   { "range": { "age" : { "gt" : 30 }} }
    }
}
```

For exact match you can [use 'term' from ES docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_most_important_queries.html#_term_query) as:

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must": [ { "term": { "field": "Apple" }},
                  { "term": { "fruit":  "Y" }} ]
    }
}
```

In Kibana use:

```
GET index_name/_search
{
"query": { 
         # your search query here
         }
}
```

Possibly this is not the best solution, but hope this helps you.

## UPDATED

Try out at [ES demo](https://demo.elastic.co/app/kibana#/dev_tools/console?_g=())

[image: TEST]

Sample code to run:

```
GET kibana_sample_data_flights/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match": {
          "OriginWeather": "Sunny"
        }},
        {"match": {
          "Cancelled": false
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```